# Randomize Slick Slides except the First Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using Slick Slider and I'm able to randomize all the slides but I want the first slide to be excluded. Lets say I have 6 slides the order would be: 1,[radomized: 3,5,4,2,6] or 1,[randomized: 6,4,3,2,5] etc. Hopefully I have provided enough information. So in a nutshell I would like the first slide to always appear first then the rest are randomized

What I have so far:

```
 $(function() {

  var slideCount = $('.slideshow > div').length;
  var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * slideCount);

  $('.slideshow').slick({
    initialSlide: randomStart,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    accessibility:true    
    });

  });
```

Comment: its not random if you are just changing the initialSlide, is it?

Comment: Hi rishipuri, sorry yes the above will give me a random start number only - so it may start at 4 then 5,6,1,2 ,3 and so on.  I suppose I'd be happy for it to be 1 - 4,5,6,1,2,3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about randomizing slides order **before** initialization of slick?
See this code:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/

And if you want the first slide to stay unchagned, just exclude it:

```
$('.slideshow > div').not(':first-child').shuffle();
```

Comment: Slap palm on forehead. Demitri very clever!- I was using that script from CSS Tricks and it didn't occur to me  use the .not(':first-child') selector . Thank you for helping me look at this in a different way :)

Comment: Glad it helped!