# Random slide order in slick image slider

Tags: javascript, random, slider, slick.js

I am using

```
      var allslides = document.querySelector(".lazy");
        for (var i = allslides.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
          allslides.appendChild(allslides.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
        };
```

to randomize the slide order in Slick carousal (image slider).

Here ".lazy" is:

```
<section class="lazy slider" data-sizes="50vw">
  <div><img src="1.png"/</div>
  <div><img src="2.png"/</div>
  <div><img src="3.png"/</div>
  <div><img src="4.png"/</div>
</section>
```

All is fine except a blank slide (or a white gap) gets inserted. Just can't get rid of it. Any clues or cues?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Is this meant to answer my question? Could you please tell what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 8):

You don't really need to manipulate the `DOM` at all. Simply hook into the `goto` method and randomly navigate to a different slide.

This is one of many possible implementations:

```
var total = $('.slick-slideshow img').length, // get the number of slides
    rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * total ); // random number

$('.slick-slideshow').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    slide: "img",
    pauseOnHover: false
})
.slickGoTo(rand); //navigate to random slide
```

You can learn more in this discussion: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/359

Comment: I think you could also set `initialSlide: rand` in the initial options

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197831/randomize-slick-slides-except-the-first-slide